# Parse Artists from string using regex

Tags: javascript, regex, string, split

I am trying to read strings like
`"Ludacris feat. Lil Jon, Drake & Elvis Presley"` into an array `["Ludacris", "Lil Jon", "Drake", "Elvis Presley"]` using javascript.

The strings always have the same structure but sometimes they have brackets around the featuring artists like `[feat. ... ]` or `(feat. ... )`

What i have right now is this:
`(\s*\b(feat)\b[.]?\s*)|(\s*,\s*)|(\s*&\s*)`

It seems to match correctly when i test it on https://regex101.com/ however, the following code doesn't work

```
var a = "Ludacris feat. Lil Jon, Drake & Elvis Presley".split(/(\s*\b(feat)\b[.]?\s*)|(\s*,\s*)|(\s*&\s*)/);
console.log(a);
```

The output is

```
[
  'Ludacris', ' feat. ',
  'feat',     undefined,
  undefined,  'Lil Jon',
  undefined,  undefined,
  ', ',       undefined,
  'Drake',    undefined,
  undefined,  undefined,
  ' & ',      'Elvis Presley'
]
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Use non-capturing groups

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try without the parentheses. Using capture groups makes you match the string separately, hence creating more undefined items if you use it with `split()`

```js
var a = "Ludacris feat. Lil Jon, Drake & Elvis Presley".split(/\s*\bfeat\b[.]?\s*|\s*,\s*|\s*&\s*/);
console.log(a);
```

Comment: thats a lot of `\s` shadowing the actual regex. can also use `.split(/feat.|,|&/).map(e => e.trim())`

Comment: This fails when the source string contains brackets `[...]` and parentheses `(...)`

Comment: @JonSkeet  is ideal for answering this question. 

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an advocate of long and complicated regex expressions. They are hard to read and reason about.

The code becomes more understandable when you break up regex processing into smaller chunks.

```js
let a = "Ludacris [feat. Lil Jon], Drake & Elvis Presley (feat. Elton John)";

// strip all '[]' and '()' characters
let noBrackets = a.replace(/[\[\]\(\)]/g, '');

// repalce all ' feat.' strings with ','
let noFeat = noBrackets.replace(/ feat\./g, ',');

// replace all ' &' with ','
let noAmpersand = noFeat.replace(/ \&/g, ',');

// split into arrays at ', '
let arr = noAmpersand.split(', ');

let result = document.getElementById('result');
result.innerHTML = 'a: ' + JSON.stringify(a);
result.innerHTML += '\n\nnoBrackets: ' +
  JSON.stringify(noBrackets);
result.innerHTML += '\nnoFeat: ' + JSON.stringify(noFeat);
result.innerHTML += '\nnoAmpersand:' +
  JSON.stringify(noAmpersand);
result.innerHTML += '\n\narr: ' + JSON.stringify(arr, null, 2);
```

```html
<pre id="result"></pre>
```